# Ubuntu 14.04 + Gnome 3.10 = cannot open settings

Tags: 14.04, gnome, system-settings

I've encountered a problem. After some time of using my ubuntu 14.04 + gnome shell i happend not to be able to open system settings. When I open it usually just nothing happens or system error occurs and it asks me to send a report.I've tried to run it from command line, but here's what i get:

```
marcin@marcin-laptop:~$ sudo gnome-control-center

(gnome-control-center.real:3201): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot derive 'GnomeControlCenter' from non-fundamental parent type 'CcShell'

(gnome-control-center.real:3201): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gnome-control-center.real:3201): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

I've found in google that

> Downgrading the library 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu1~saucy3 to 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu45 fixed the issue for me too.
>
> (source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1309419/comments/10)

might help but i don't know how to do it (I'm still new to Linux system).
I would really appreciate if you could help :)

Comment: Try the command and check gconftool -g /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option

Comment: Unforunately: "Couldn't set value for "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option"" This is what i get after executing this command.

Comment: Ok the issue is solved, I edited my first post and added the solution. Thanks @vembutech :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @Rinzwind, i am not yet used to using stackoverflow types of sites and i often forget to do the most important things :)

And where can i mark your answer for deleting? :P

Comment: It's ok... you do not want to know what I messed up in my 1st few days here :D Feel free to create your own answer, accept and upvote it.I'll remove mine if you do :)

Comment: It's already done :)

Comment: @Zwierzak nope.. I still have the accepted vote so can't remove it yet ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind i guess i have removed my "tick" from your answer, do I need to do anything else? :)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-control-center
```

It didn't help so i ran this one and it solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

copied from the question

---

@SOLUTION!
This worked for me :)
Firstly, I ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-control-center
```

It didn't help so i ran this one and it solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.
Thanks for the help anyways :D